# Add a Button within the content type overlay window for the url link

Tags: 7, nodes

There is any way to add a button into the content type for example Article as show in the below figure

[image]

there is any module for adding the button within the content type in drupal 7.

Comment: Have you completed this task?

Answer (score 1):

The page in your screen shot is a 'node add' page for a particular content type in your drupal site. Therefore the best way to add more elements there is to utilize hook_form_alter()

```
<?php
function custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'mynodetype_node_form') {
    dsm($form); // This function is available via Devel module. Here, it shows you the contents of $form in a structured manner, so that you know where to make the change to add a button.
    // Add code here to add button in the form etc.
  }
}
?>
```

The above code snippet assumes your module name is `custom` and your content type name is `mynodetype`

To understand what code you need to write to add new form element (in your case a button), refer drupal form api - http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7

Comment: How to see the devel output.Here my node type name is External News.So I replaced the mynodetype_node_form with External News_node_form

Comment: 1. Any node type has a human name and a machine name. The machine name never has a space. You need to use machine name in the function.

Comment: 2. Devel module provides this function called `dsm()` that takes in any array or an object and shows that on the site in a easy to explore way. The output is visible in the "message area" of the site.